# Freezing the main thread after the TCPListener start

Tags: vb.net, tcp

Currently i am creating a simple chat app which using TCP my problem is when i click on the button for start the TCP the window is freezing and i cannot do nothing (and it remain freez even if i connected with a TCP client) I tried to put the TCP-server into another thread but somehow it this case it is not working and i cannot even connect with TCP-client

Here is my code

```
Sub TCPServerStart()
    TCPListenerz = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1000)
    TCPListenerz.Start()
    TCPServer = TCPListenerz.AcceptSocket
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Dim adddress As IPAddress = CType(TCPServer.RemoteEndPoint, IPEndPoint).Address
    ConnectedTo.Text = adddress.ToString
End Sub
Private Sub TCP_connction_type_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TCP_connction_type.Click
    TCPServerStart
End Sub
Sub TCPServcerSub()
    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TCPTextbox.Text)
    TCPServer.Send(sendbytes)
    ''   TCPServer.SendFile("")
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim rcvbytes(TCPServer.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    TCPServer.Receive(rcvbytes)
    TextBox4.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)
End Sub ''TCP Recive
```

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: `AcceptSocket` is a synchronous method so of course you're blocking on the UI thread. If you don't want to block then use one of the asynchronous options.

Comment: Thanks a lot i used another solution which is working so i found a way but thanks a lot